# Unity Coroutine not working across scenes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I am calling a Coroutine shown below, which is attached to a `DontDestroyOnLoad` objects that persists across scenes.

```
IEnumerator InitMaxScore()
{
    Debug.Log("will wait for some time");
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
    GameObject[] coins = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Coin");
    Debug.Log("coins length == " + coins.Length);
    if (coins.Length > 0)
    {
        maxScoreInitialized = true;
        maxScore = score + coins.Length * 10;
        foreach (GameObject healthPickup in GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Health"))
        {
            maxScore += healthPickup.GetComponent<Pickups>().pointsForLifePickup;
        }
        Debug.Log("maxScore inti == " + maxScore);
    }
    yield return null;
}
```

This Coroutine is called in the `OnLevelWasLoaded` event of the said gameobject which is set to `DontDestroyOnLoad` on awake as shown below.

```
private void Awake()
{
    int numGameSessions = FindObjectsOfType<GameSession>().Length;
    if (numGameSessions > 1)
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
    else
    {
        DifficultyManagement.setDifficulty(Difficulty.One); // start the game with diff one always
        DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
    }
}
```

While the log "will wait for some time" in the Coroutine is getting printed, Debug.Log("coins length == " + coins.Length) is not getting printed all the times. I am certainly not destroying the said gameobject for the entire duration of my game that might have caused the Coroutine to behave this way. The behaviour is not consistent either, sometimes it works, sometimes it does not, and I am like why can't you make up your mind.

I have been banging my head on this for a long time and could not seem to fix this, any leads would be appreciated to lift my mental block :/

Comment: How do you start this coroutine?

Comment: using `StartCoroutine(InitMaxScore());` in the `OnLevelWasLoaded()` function

Comment: Strangely, it has been working fine ever since I posted this question. but is not working in my build.

Comment: This is horribly strange, the Coroutine was working as expected in Unity. I restarted Unity without any code or scene changes, and it broke again.

Comment: Will you load the scene that contains this script multiple times?

Comment: Yes, many many times. It is the only scene in my game apart from main menu and game over scene, it reloads on player death, and on many other occasions as well.

Comment: As I tested, the undestroyed script works well, but the destroyed script will also trigger `OnLevelWasLoaded` once when you switch back the the scene. You may check which script print the log.

Comment: oh, is that so. why would they make it this way, how do i solve it then? :(

Comment: how do i check that which script prints the log?

Comment: You can add hash code in log, `Debug.Log("will wait for some time " + this.GetHashCode());`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OnLevelWasLoaded is deprecated, consider using sceneLoaded event:

```
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

private void Awake()
{
    int numGameSessions = FindObjectsOfType<GameSession>().Length;
    if (numGameSessions > 1)
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
    else
    {
        DifficultyManagement.setDifficulty(Difficulty.One); // start the game with diff one always
        DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
        SceneManager.sceneLoaded += (scene, mode) => StartCoroutine(InitMaxScore());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I did this and it worked. I hope that this will also fix a bunch of other issues which were eating my head since last few days.

Comment: I wish I had posted it earlier here, would have saved a lot of time.

Comment: Didn't you notice the log print twice when scene changes?

Comment: The collapse option in the unity console was on, that's why I did not notice it getting printed twice. Should have paid attention to it :(

Comment: Thank you @shingo for your incredible help.